# Unsupported Protocol Scheme Bosh Deployment

Tags: ruby, cloud-foundry, cf-bosh, bosh

i am new to Bosh and trying to create my first release.However,when deploying the created release i am getting this error message.I also tried to download a release published by the community and get it running but i am getting the same error message.

```
 L Error: Action Failed get_task: Task 91c8b925-fb75-49cb-4f28-8d783013b255 result: Compiling package nginx: Fetching package nginx: Fetching package blob 22a70ff2-5c50-4623-bf5b-47f4f7bf8ed8: Getting blob from inner blobstore: Getting blob from inner blobstore: Shelling out to bosh-blobstore-dav cli: Running command: 'bosh-blobstore-dav -c /var/vcap/bosh/etc/blobstore-dav.json get 22a70ff2-5c50-4623-bf5b-47f4f7bf8ed8 /var/vcap/data/tmp/bosh-blobstore-externalBlobstore-Get484019718', stdout: 'Error running app - Getting dav blob 22a70ff2-5c50-4623-bf5b-47f4f7bf8ed8: Get /d8/22a70ff2-5c50-4623-bf5b-47f4f7bf8ed8: unsupported protocol scheme ""', stderr: '': exit status 1
Task 43 | 20:39:58 | Error: Action Failed get_task: Task 91c8b925-fb75-49cb-4f28-8d783013b255 result: Compiling package nginx: Fetching package nginx: Fetching package blob 22a70ff2-5c50-4623-bf5b-47f4f7bf8ed8: Getting blob from inner blobstore: Getting blob from inner blobstore: Shelling out to bosh-blobstore-dav cli: Running command: 'bosh-blobstore-dav -c /var/vcap/bosh/etc/blobstore-dav.json get 22a70ff2-5c50-4623-bf5b-47f4f7bf8ed8 /var/vcap/data/tmp/bosh-blobstore-externalBlobstore-Get484019718', stdout: 'Error running app - Getting dav blob 22a70ff2-5c50-4623-bf5b-47f4f7bf8ed8: Get /d8/22a70ff2-5c50-4623-bf5b-47f4f7bf8ed8: unsupported protocol scheme ""', stderr: '': exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It was due to using ubuntu-trusty stemcell.Updated to ubuntu-jammy and it works as my VM is also running ubuntu-jammy.